# Export Excel into a formatted Powerpoint

Tags: excel, powerpoint

Is there a way for me to export a excel sheet with multiple columns of information into a formatted powerpoint?
  I would like it so that a single row was its own slide and each column could be assigned a textbox? Is this even possible?

Comment: What have you tried? Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It's possible.  It's a lot of work, but it's possible.  There are add-ins for PPT that will do the job for you, though.  Google e.g. mail merge powerpoint for a couple options.  Disclaimer:  I wrote one of them.